# Ambiguous {curve} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

In the descripton of the [{curve}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=30)-tag it says:

> Curve is a Latex class for typesetting resumes

But when I look at the questions with this tag I just discover 4 of 34 which correspond to this description. All others use this tag in the context of [{Ti*k*Z-pgf}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) or [{pgfplots}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots).

So I would suggest removing the tag and using for example the more common tag [{resume}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) for the 4 correct uses. For deleting, I think a high reputation is needed.

Is there any better way for such suggestions than to have a question here?

Comment: I don't think the [tag:curve] tag is ambiguous.  People are just abusing it.  As for retagging the four correct ones and deleting it, I agree.  Deleting non-empty tags can only be done by a moderator.  Empty tags are pruned automatically.

Comment: I suggest naming the tag for the class [tag:curve-class].

Comment: curve for tikz or pgfplots is also weird. Any package can have curves in it. I don't think graphical use is correct neither line nor fill in that sense. Asking specifically about curves is basically a TikZ or pgfplots question anyways.

Comment: I agree with both @yo' and  percusse on this: having a 'curve' tag makes little sense, no more so than having a 'line' or 'rectangle' tag. But since it's less obvious that 'curve' *is* a class, and it will be misapplied, changing it to 'curve-class' makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Should we remove all [curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve) tags attached to graphical questions?

Comment: I renamed the tags of the 4 correct uses to [{curve-class}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve-class) according to @yo' s suggestion. The tag [{curve}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve) may be removed by a moderator.

Comment: Moderators cannot remove non-empty tags, only developers can. Moderators can rename, or merge, or synonymise tags. (cc @Henri) And there is not really a better way to deal with such tags/ suggestions than meta.

Comment: btw: you can use `[tag:curve]` for easier hotlinking, i.e. [tag:curve]

Comment: @Martin-マーチン A mod can blacklist a tag, AFAIK.

Comment: @yo' Only SE developers can blacklist a tag. See the procedure given in the answer to [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/368324).

Comment: @dexteritas Perhaps each incorrect tag could be removed from the posts, and then the tag _would_ be empty.  And then, it could be removed or "pruned automatically" as Henri Menke suggested.  Though tedious, it would solve the problem.

Comment: @sk8forether That's right. But the removing of the tag should only be done by users with 2000+ reputation, so that no review is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really a better way to deal with such tags/ suggestions than meta. (Martin)

**As result and summary of the comments:**

- I renamed the tags of the 4 correct uses to [curve-class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve-class) according to yo' s suggestion.
- All other uses of [curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curve) were removed manually.
- Empty tags are pruned automatically. (Henri Menke)

**Notes:**

- Moderators cannot remove non-empty tags, only developers can. Moderators can rename, or merge, or synonymise tags. (Martin)
- [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/368324)
- Only SE developers can blacklist a tag. See the procedure given in the answer to [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/368324)